# Circumventing a ban from the UK using another passport with a different name and dates of birth?

Tags: uk, passports, legal, dual-nationality, visa-bans

I have a 10 year UK ban on my South African passport but I have a Zimbabwean passport as well with different name and date of birth. What will happen if I use this?

Comment: How did you come to have two passports with different names and DOB? And when you say 'different name' how different is it? A slightly different spelling or completely different?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you don't have a ban “on your passport”, you have been banned as a person.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for advice on doing something blatantly illegal (cf. http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-should-questions-answers-on-how-to-do-something-illegal-be-treated)

Comment: Possibly you end up in a Zimbabwean prison after the British embassy turns you in for submitting false documents.

Comment: Answer: you might get away with it and you might not.  We have no way of knowing. If you get caught, you can be certain that you will be banned for at least the *next* ten years, if not longer.

Comment: @GayotFow meaning?  He should be worrying about appealing the ban? Or is it something else?

Comment: I think this is on-topic, and it's not looking for advice to break the law -- it's a genuine question on what would happen that's completely answerable. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I can see how someone might have two names but how can you have two dates of birth? Are you asking "what happens if I use a fake passport"? If not then what are you asking?

Comment: @AE In fact, not all countries are very strict regarding date of birth, including many eastern European countries. I know several people with passports that indicate a date of birth several days after they were actually born and it's perfectly legal.

Comment: You cannot enter UK without undergoing border control. This applies even if you are coming from a Schengen country (it's not part of the Schengen area) or if your country has agreements for exemption of tourist visa. Most likely the ban applies to you as a person, not on your passport. In the unlikely case you cleared security upon arrival, you'd probably be facing prosecution/deportation as soon as police became aware of you being in the country.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter, that's interesting, I didn't know that. But I don't fully understand - why would I ever fill in a form with a date of birth that's not my own? (Assuming no intention to mislead). It's not like people forget their own birthdays. The classic mistake is putting today's date as the DOB, not putting the 5th when it was really the 1st.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter, you refer to the case where the passport differs from the birth certificate; this is a case where two passports have different dob's and only one can be consistent with the birth certificate.

Comment: @Lee Why did the UK ban you?

Comment: @GayotFow I don't see how that makes a difference. For all we know the passport with a date of birth that does not math the birth certificate actually lists the correct date of birth.

Answer (score 13):

Zimbabwe and South Africa are both [visa-national countries](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/zimbabwe/tourism), so your question resolves to: "*what happens if I apply for entry clearance where a ban is still in effect on a different travel document?*"  You might be thinking that nobody has ever thought of this before and that there's a loophole available.

The previous use and ban on your South African passport was accompanied by the capture and storage of your biometrics.  When you apply for entry clearance with your Zim passport, you will need to enrol your biometrics.  When those are put into the system it will find a match with your previous removal.  At that point you will be called in for an interview so they can get a voice recording and video of you, and then you'll get a refusal notice in the mail.  A second ban will kick in, but I don't know (and I doubt anyone knows for certain) if multiple  bans are served concurrently or consecutively.  So the only thing that would happen is the loss of the GBP 83 application fee, another ban, and the disclosure of your Zim passport details to the other '[five eyes' members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) and Schengen.  That's the best outcome you could hope for.

The only other case is if your previous ban was the result of clandestine entry to the UK. In this case if you used your Zim passport to somehow either get a visa or effect a clandestine entry, UKVI would most likely refer you to the [Crown Prosecution Service](http://www.cps.gov.uk/) under Section 2 of the [Fraud Act 2006](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/35/section/2) because you would be benefiting by accessing the UK whilst representing yourself with a different identity. That would leave you with a criminal record and possibly cause the Zim or SA government to revoke your passport(s). It can be a quick way to go from two passports to zero passports.