# Deported from the US with no stamp; home country said passport was blacklisted

Tags: usa, passports

I was once deported from the US with no stamp on my passport. My home country said the passport was blacklisted.

What does this mean? Can I still travel or get a visa on the same passport or should I get a new passport? What does a passport being on a blacklist mean, if the passport saves the travel record in it?

Comment: For what reason were you deported? Did you overstay or were you not let in when you arrived in the US? Who said you were blacklisted and did they give you a letter or similar saying that?

Comment: @James Being ‘blacklisted’ applies to a person, not their passport, so if you do have an adverse travel record getting a new passport won’t change that. See for example https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60504/circumventing-a-ban-from-the-uk-using-another-passport-with-a-different-name-and

Comment: Were you actually _deported_ (thrown out of the country after being convicted of a criminal offence) or just _refused entry_ (not allowed in when you tried to visit)?

Comment: @Traveller I’m pretty sure there are blacklists of passports, like those that are known to have been stolen.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the scanty information you provided, the following are my answers. Now to be clear if your passport was **blacklisted by your own country**, then game over. You are not going to be traveling anywhere because your own country will prevent you from traveling.

However if you mean your country said USA had blacklisted you, the following answers will clarify your confusion.

> Soo what that means?

Being deported means you have a ban from entering the USA, [usually five, ten, twenty years or permanent](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/how-long-after-deportation-must-i-wait-before-returning-the-us.html) depending on why you we banned. It also means other countries which find out will view you suspiciously. It does not mean they will automatically deny you visas.

> Can I still travel or get visa on the same passport or should I get a
>   new pp?

That is a decision you have to make yourself. Personally I would use the same passport particularly since there is no deportation stamp in it.

> Or my travel dreams r over?

Not necessarily. Many countries do not ask if you have been previously deported and do not have that information. Even if you tell them (do not tell them if they don’t ask), some may choose to overlook it depending on what caused the deportation.

> What is this passport was in blacklist?

Nobody knows, unlikely. However the USA definitely has you on a blacklist, likely Canada and **maybe** other members of the Five Eyes Treaty.

> If passport itself saves travel record in it?

No. Passport chips are currently read only.

Comment: His question is about his home country having blacklisted his passport. Some countries do that especially if a person was deported from a third country for forged documents or criminal activities. Normally, a person will be banned from leaving his country for X number of years. Without knowing the OP's home country, it is impossible to suggest any possible recourse.